# split a string into two divs, and split inside the string php

Tags: php, string, wordpress, split, custom-fields

I have a website on wordpress using ACF custom fields.
I have a custom field with around 100 lines of text.
a date and a text like this :

```
2003-01 PARIS RATP PHILIDOR
2003-01 BORDEAUX TRAMWAY
2003-02 ILE-DE-FRANCE ÉCOLE DES MINES
2003-05 PARIS CITROëN
2003-05 PARIS TRAVERSIÈRE
```

first of all I wanted to split the field (called "projets") in two separate divs, the first 50 lines in one div and the rest in another div :
here is the PHP code i'm using :

```
<div class="columns_projets_1">
<p><?php 
$string = get_field('projets'); 
$array = explode("\n", $string);
for($i = 0; $i <50; $i++){
echo $array[$i];
}
?></p>
</div>

<div class="columns_projets_2">
<p><?php 
$string = get_field('projets'); 
$array = explode("\n", $string);
for($i = 50; $i <count($array)-1; $i++){
echo $array[$i];
}
?></p>
</div>
```

It works perfectly !
but I would like for each line to get the date separatly for the text, to put the date in one div and the text in another one... like this :

```
<div class="date">2003-01</><div class="text">PARIS RATP PHILIDOR</div>
```

but I can't find how to code this, to have the first php code, and the next to split inside the line... I heard about substrings, I tried eveything but it's not working...
Can anybody help me ? would be really great !
I hope you can understand me !
thanks a lot

Mattieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo HTML too.
For instance:

```
for($i = 0; $i <50; $i++){
    $dateAndText= explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
    echo '<div class="date">'.$dateAndText[0].'</div>';
    echo '<div class="text">'.$dateAndText[1].'</div>';
}
```

Although a cleaner way to do this would be something like this:

```
<?php  for($i = 0; $i <50; $i++): 
    $dateAndText = explode(' ', $array[$i], 2); ?>

    <div class="date"><?php echo $dateAndText[0]; ?></div>
    <div class="text"><?php echo $dateAndText[1]; ?></div>

 <?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but when I add your code in my own code, I get a server error... I can't find what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I forgot the $ in my response. Change dateAndText for $dateAndText or copy paste from my response after i edit

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
$test = explode(' ', $array[$i], 2);
```

`$test[0]` will be with the date, and in `$test[1]` you will have the rest of line.

For more information:
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.explode.php

Comment: +1 for the link to the manual. [so] is not about fixing code but  knowing how to fix yourself.